# Does f:ajax have any options like global=true/false as p:ajax?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Does f:ajax have any options like global=true/false as p:ajax ?? If not then what is the replacement for the same to avoid my p:ajaxStatus to show loading image for all my inputText components except my commandButton.

Comment: no f:ajax doesn't have such a feature, why you wouldn't use p:ajax instead ?

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it ? Because I cannot avoid using f:ajax .

Comment: Which event you are using in the inputText s ?

Comment: I have used event as event="blur"

Comment: And inputTexts are prime or h ?

Comment: Input texts are prime ....